# asp.net:export gridview to excel with images

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a gridview in web form that contains images resized to 40X40 px but when I export the gridview to excel the images return to there original size how I can export the gridview to excel with images resized to my desired size

this is the export code I use

```
Try
GridView2.AllowPaging = False

Response.Clear()
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=ComputerParts.xls")
Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel"
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode
Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetPreamble())

Dim sw As System.IO.StringWriter = New System.IO.StringWriter()
Dim hw As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter = New HtmlTextWriter(sw)

txtSelectedComputer.RenderControl(hw)
txtEmployeeName.RenderControl(hw)
GridView2.RenderControl(hw)

Response.Write(sw.ToString())
Response.End()

GridView2.AllowPaging = True
```

Catch ex As SqlException
    Masterlbl1.Text = GeneralFuctions.interpret_error_number(ex.Number)
Catch ex As Exception
    Masterlbl2.Text = "حدث خطأ غير متوقع. مصدر الخطأ:" & ex.Source.ToString
End Try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see the HTML output so I cannot sure how you define the width and height of the images in your GridView control. Therefore, I took a simple experiment and got a interesting result.

My Excel is 2007. I use Notepad to write a simple HTML page contains one table. Then I put an image with the following tag:

```
<img src="test.png" style="width=10px; height: 10px">
```

The image will remain actual size in Excel.

But it will shrink with following tag:

```
<img src="test.png" width="10" height="10">
```

I think Excel use the old-fasioned HTML parser to show the content. If you use Image control of ASP.NET, it will generate the HTML with style property. Maybe you will need some workarounds to change the output. I do not know what version of Excel you use. I hope this result will help.

Comment: interesting, you are right. but how we can modify the export code to do things well

Comment: You can add an entry in Attributes property of the Image control. ex. myImage.Attributes.Add("width", "10"). It is better you can let this statement only be executed when export to Excel.

Comment: the attribute is set correctly in my webform in the correct syntax but the export code auto generate it in the new way and excel understands the old way only